# Why is the local variable ks declared in the HashMap.keySet()?

Tags: java

I looked at the source code java.util.HashMap and saw the following code:

```
public Set<K> keySet() {
    Set<K> ks;
    return (ks = keySet) == null ? (keySet = new KeySet()) : ks;
}
```

*(Windows, java version "1.8.0_111")*

On my MacBook it looks like this:

```
public Set<K> keySet() {
    Set<K> ks = keySet;
    if (ks == null) {
        ks = new KeySet();
        keySet = ks;
    }
    return ks;
}
```

*(MacOs X Sierra, java version "1.8.0_121")*

Why do both variants declare a local variable ks? Why is it not written like this:

```
public Set<K> keySet() {
    if (keySet == null) {
        keySet = new KeySet();
    }
    return keySet;
}
```

or

```
public Set<K> keySet() {
    return keySet == null ? (keySet = new KeySet()) : keySet;
}
```

Comment: @MarounMaroun I dont see it being volatile. The only modifier I see is `transient`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as I can tell this is an optimization that is pretty neat.

This was previously written like this:

```
if (keySet == null) { // volatile read
         keySet = new AbstractSet<K>() { // volatile write
          ....

return keySet; // volatile read
```

These operations can not be re-ordered because there are memory barriers that are inserted here. So it would look like this:

```
 [StoreLoad]
 // volatile read
 [LoadLoad]
 [LoadStore]

 [StoreStore]
 [LoadStore]
 // volatile write
 [StoreLoad]

 [StoreLoad] // there's probably just one barrier here instead of two
 // volatile read
 [LoadLoad]
 [LoadStore]
```

There are lots of barriers here and the most expensive would be the `StoreLoad` that is emitted on `x86`.

Suppose we drop the `volatile` here. Since there are no barriers inserted these operations can be re-ordered in any way they please and there are two racy reads here of the `keySet` variable.

We can have a single racy read and store the variable into a local field(since they are local, they are thread safe - no one can change the reference that is locally declared), the only problem as far as I can see is that multiple threads might see a null reference at the same time and initialize it with an empty  `KeySet` and potentially doing too much work; but that is most probably cheaper than the barriers.

On the other hand if some threads sees a non-null reference, it will 100% see a fully initialized object and that is the comment about `final` fields. If all objects are final the JMM guarantees a "freeze" action after the constructor; or in simpler words (IMO) if all fields are final and initialized in the constructor there are two barriers inserted after it: `LoadStore` and `LoadLoad`; thus achieving the same effect.

Answer (score 12):

JavaDoc has the answer:

```
/**
 * Since there is no synchronization performed while accessing these fields,
 * it is expected that java.util.Map view classes using these fields have
 * no non-final fields (or any fields at all except for outer-this). Adhering
 * to this rule would make the races on these fields benign.
 *
 * It is also imperative that implementations read the field only once,
 * as in:
 *
 * public Set<K> keySet() {
 *   Set<K> ks = keySet;  // single racy read
 *   if (ks == null) {
 *     ks = new KeySet();
 *     keySet = ks;
 *   }
 *   return ks;
 * }
 *}
 */
transient Set<K> keySet;
```

Comment: you're right about the comment, I've tried to explain it a bit more